# Drawing a graph partition with the networkX package in Python

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graph-drawing

I have a graph object `G` with nodes from `0` to `n-1` and two lists `L1` `L2` which are a partition of the nodes of `G`. I'd like to draw `G` in such a way that the nodes result divided in two blocks: one relative to `L1` and the other relative to `L2`. The aim of the picture should be to evidentiate the connections between `L1` and `L2`. Can you help me do perform this task?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have you tried?  Can you show us an example of your code or what you are trying to draw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw each graph separately and use a disjoint product to generate a new graph that shows the edges:

[image]

```
import networkx as nx

n1, n2 = 10, 10

# Define two random graphs
g1 = nx.gnm_random_graph(n1,20)
g2 = nx.gnm_random_graph(n2,20)
pos1 = nx.graphviz_layout(g1,prog='dot')
pos2 = nx.graphviz_layout(g2,prog='dot')

# Shift graph2
shift = 400
for key in pos2:
    pos2[key] = (pos2[key][0]+shift, pos2[key][1])

# Combine the graphs and remove all edges
g12 = nx.disjoint_union(g1,g2)
for i,j in g12.edges():
    g12.remove_edge(i,j)

# Add the conjoined edges
g12.add_edge(5, 7+n1)
g12.add_edge(2, 3+n1)
g12.add_edge(8, 7+n1)

# Set the new pos for g12
pos12 = pos1.copy()
for node in pos2:
    pos12[node+n2] = pos2[node]

# Show the results, make the conjoined edges darker

import pylab as plt
nx.draw_networkx(g1,pos=pos1,alpha=0.5)
nx.draw_networkx(g2,pos=pos2,alpha=0.5)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g12,pos=pos12,width=5)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```