# How to separate an unconnected networkx graph into multiple mutually disjoint graphs that are connected?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-algorithm

I have a `networkx.Graph` object representing a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) whose [nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_(graph_theory)) represent English words, and whose [edges](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphEdge.html) between two wnodes imply that the two words that those nodes represent have at least one shared [cognitive synonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_synonymy) between their [synsets](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/synset) (i.e. a non-empty [intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory))). I hope that is interesting or useful background to someone, but my problem is a more widely applicable one relating to graphs, `networkx`, and Python.

Many [induced subgraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_subgraph) (edge-induced, or vertex-induced) of this graph are both [edge disjoint and vertex disjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms), and I'd like to separate these subgraphs into their own `networkx.Graph` objects such that they're connected and mutually disjoint. It is possible that I'm just using the wrong search terms for the `networkx` documentation, but [I didn't see anything promising related to "disjoint"](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/search.html?q=disjoint&check_keywords=yes&area=default). Here are some examples from a tiny portion of the graph.

[image]

I looked through the [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&q=%5bnetworkx%5d%20%20disjoint) for `[networkx] disjoint` on Stack Overflow and didn't see what I was looking for. For example, [one result talked about getting the induced subgraph when there's already have an edge set to induce from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092574/what-is-the-algorithm-to-get-disjoint-set-from-edgelist-with-weights/35094136#35094136). Or [another post talked about trying to draw two disjoint graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691948/drawing-a-graph-partition-with-the-networkx-package-in-python/27158933#27158933), but that's assuming you already have them. Related to the graph theory aspect of my question, but not the `networkx` aspect, is that apparently there's [such a thing as a flood fill algorithm that might address the part of my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011513/topologically-sort-directed-graph-into-buckets-for-disjoint-sub-graphs).

Now, for a minimum working example, let's create a small random graph but ensure that it is disconnected.

```py
import networkx as nx

g = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(10, 0.3)

while nx.is_connected(g):
    g = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(10, 0.3)
```

At this point, we have a graph `g`. What I'm thinking of is somethine like below, where I occupy a list of the graphs that are to be mutually disjoint. I need to not only add more graphs as I loop over the nodes, but also update the graphs as I go. I thought maybe unions of induced graphs might work, but the `nx.disjoint_union_all` and `nx.union` are either going to force the graphs to be disjoint by relabelling (I don't want this) or expect the graphs to already be disjoint.

```
graphs = []

for node in g.nodes(): # same 'g' we made above
    if graphs:
        pass
    else:
        graphs.append(g.subgraph([i for i in g.neighbors(node)] +\
                                 [node]).copy())
```

**How can I separate an unconnected networkx graph into multiple mutually disjoint graphs that are connected?**

Comment: Is your graph directed?  The graphs you're showing in your examples are undirected, but you're also using the term "weakly connected", which implies directed.  If undirected, use `nx.connected_components`.  If directed, use `nx.connected_components(nx.Graph(G))` [first converts it to undirected]

Comment: Oops, that's a mistake in language on my part. I am working with undirected graphs. I'll fix the wording. Thanks for the feedback. It looks like you have a potential answer; please post it as one so I can accept it if it works! :P

Comment: I'm busy now, so I'm more than happy for anyone else to fill in the details.  I may not get back to it for a few days.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for connected components.
Consider the following graph.

[image]

```
components = [g.subgraph(c).copy() for c in nx.connected_components(g)]
for idx,g in enumerate(components,start=1):
    print(f"Component {idx}: Nodes: {g.nodes()} Edges: {g.edges()}")
```

Output:

```
Component 1: Nodes: [0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] Edges: [(0, 2), (0, 6), (1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 7), (1, 8), (2, 5), (5, 7), (6, 8), (7, 9), (8, 9)]
Component 2: Nodes: [3, 4] Edges: [(3, 4)]
```